# How to download .msi file in Java

Tags: java

I want to download .msi file using Java.  I have tried to download file using following code

```
PrintWriter out = null;
FileInputStream fileToDownload = null;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
try {
        out = response.getWriter();
        fileToDownload = new FileInputStream(DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY + FILE_NAME);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileToDownload));

        //response.setContentType("application/text");
        //response.setContentType("application/x-msi");
        //response.setContentType("application/msi");
        //response.setContentType("octet-stream");
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        //response.setContentType("application/x-7z-compressed");
        //response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=" +FILE_NAME );
        response.setContentLength(fileToDownload.available());

        System.out.println("\n now file download is starting");
        String NextLine = "";
        while((NextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            out.println(NextLine);
        }
        out.flush();                                

    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.write("<center><h2>The Installer is not Available on Server</h2></center>");
        System.out.println("\n Got Exception while getting the input Stream from the file==>"+e);
        log.error("Error::", e);
    }
    finally{
        if(null != bufferedReader){
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("\n Error in closing buffer Reader==>"+e);
                log.error("Error::", e);
            }
        }// End of if

        if(null != fileToDownload){
            try {
                fileToDownload.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("\n Error in closing input stream==>"+e);
                log.error("Error::", e);
            }
        }// End of if
    }// End of finally
```

Comment: Have you checked the msi for corruption with a basic file download, entirely outside of Java? Maybe it didn't upload properly, because any of those content types should work, unless something else is very wrong with the code leading up to it.

Comment: The content type has no effect on the actual data being downloaded. How does the rest of the code look?

Comment: The .msi file I have pasted at particular directory and downloading same for use at client machine. Following code tried used

Comment: show more code ... it looks like servlet ?

Comment: I am not able to put function because of restriction. So above adjusted max part of code

Comment: click on edit below question...and paste this code.

Comment: What errors do you get? Your code could potentially change the newlines and encoding of characters. Is there any reason for reading the file as strings instead of blocks of bytes?

Comment: Working without error for selected contentType but in case of .msi file download getting error when installing that "This installation package could not be opened. Contact application vendor to verify that is valid Window Installer package".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can't read binary(msi) file with `readline()` in this case.Your Code is totally wrong and will not work.
Here is a simple function which lets you do what you want.

```
    private void doDownload( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp,String filename, String original_filename )throws IOException
            {
            File f = new File(filename);
            int  length   = 0;
            ServletOutputStream op = resp.getOutputStream();
            ServletContext context  = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
            String  mimetype = context.getMimeType( filename );
            resp.setContentType( (mimetype != null) ? mimetype : "application/octet-stream" );
            resp.setContentLength( (int)f.length() );
            resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + original_filename + "\"" );
            byte[] bbuf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)){
            op.write(bbuf,0,length);
            }
            in.close();
            op.flush();
            op.close();
        }
```

Create `doDownload()` function in your `servlet` and pass requierd parameters to that function from `doGet`,`doPost` or whatever valid place you like.

**Parameters:**

- @param req The request
- @param resp The response
- @param filename The name of the file you want to download.
- @param original_filename The name the browser should receive.